Bounds for the solution of Riccati-like equation
Let we have the matrix Riccati-like equation with positive sign at quadratic term
$$
AX+XA^{T}+XBB^TX+Q=0,
$$
$Q$ is a positive-definite matrix, $A$ is a stable (Hurwitz) matrix.
Is it possible to state the bounds for its solution in terms of $\lambda_\min(X)$ and $\lambda_\max(X)$?
